# How to make my CSS transition smoother/work on different browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a page that changes background image when you click a button. Code pen: http://codepen.io/meek/pen/EPLZpW

```
body {
  background: url('https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/meek-img/1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

The two big problems with the way I'm doing this currently are:

1. It flat out doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox.
2. The animation isn't smooth at all. It switches to a blank background for an instant, then the animation runs. Is there a way to prevent this, or is it unavoidable due to loading times? If so are there other ways to implement this function that would circumvent this? At first, I thought of animating with jQuery, but was told that this wasn't optimal.

Comment: `background` is a big, general property.  What are you expecting it to do?  Is it `background-position`? `background-image`? Are you expecting the image to fade in? Is that it?

Comment: background image property is not animatable in [CSS3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#background-image) - you should preload your images so you don't get the blank

Comment: @JaromandaX preloading the images solves the weird animation problem. Next I will animate the image opacity instead of the background. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a transition on the full property `background` could possibly create some wonky effects. Especially when images are involved. Directly doing these transitions on background images is very demanding for your browser. And, as mentioned by you, does not behave consistently in different browsers.

A better idea is to do a transition or animation on `opacity` of an element (like a div) having that background property. This way the browser would not have to worry about transitioning the image, only about transitioning the div, which would result in a much easier task for your browser. If you want to change the background of your page, you would then simply add a div with that background image.

I've included a snippet, base on your code, to demonstrate the general idea. You'll also notice, I only preload the image when the image is requested as background image. This way the user only downloads the images he gets to see. My demo uses jQuery, but it could easily be integrated using vanilla JS.

```js
function preload_img (src, callback) {
  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    if( callback && typeof callback === 'function' ) {
      callback( img );
    }
  };
  
  img.src = src;
}

var imgs = [
  "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/meek-img/1.jpg",
  "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/meek-img/2.jpg",
  "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/meek-img/3.jpg", 
  "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/meek-img/4.jpg", 
  "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/meek-img/5.jpg", 
  "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/meek-img/6.jpg", 
  "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/meek-img/7.jpg", 
  "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/meek-img/8.jpg", 
  "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/meek-img/9.jpg" 
];

function change_bg() {
  var random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length);
  preload_img( imgs[random_index], function( img ) {
    $('<div>')
      .addClass('bg-image')
      .css('background-image', 'url(' + img.src + ')')
      .appendTo('body')
    ;
  } );
}

$( 'button' ).click( function() {
  change_bg();
} );

change_bg();
```

```css
@keyframes fadein
{
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

.bg-image
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: fadein 1s;
  background-size: cover;
}

.mimi
{
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="mimi">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">click me</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer!

Comment: Thanks for saving my time in writing a demo as answer myself :P

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider loading the new image on top of the current image with 0 opacity and then transition the opacity to 1. After that you can remove the image below.

Also make sure that the image is fully loaded before starting the transition.

Adding the new image on change can be done with append() and then when the new image has loaded you can add a class to it with opacity 1.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how I use append()? I'm inexperienced with jQuery, but from what I understand append() adds HTML to an element, and the background images I'm using are CSS parameters.

Comment: You can add html to an element with append and add a style tag with the image css beforehand. If you want I can make a demo tomorrow